# Correct Use of "Resort to"

Tags: grammaticality

Are "resort to" or "resorted to" (phrasal verbs followed by a preposition) always negative?  For example, is it always incorrect to write any of the following sentences, or are there circumstances under which they would be acceptable?

- It began to rain, so we resorted to moving the event to the lodge.
- The chairman then resorted to a helpful, detailed account of the
  incident.
- If the proposal is well received, we will be able to resort to
  disclosing the dollar figures.
- The neck brace worked wonders, so the doctor was glad he resorted to
  it.

Comment: Please do not put your email in questions.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/resort+to

Answer (score 1):

None of these are correct, unless they are a last-ditch effort.  For example, the doctor may have "resorted" to the neck brace, after he determined something else would not work.  This is the only one that I would say ever has a remote possibility of using "resort."  Review this definition from Merriam-Webster for more help: "the act of doing or using something especially because no other choices are possible."

Answer (score 0):

The examples are not quite appropriate.

However, there's at least one usage of the idiom *resort to* without a negative connotation: ***to frequent***, *to go to a place that one frequents*. The sense 'place frequently visited' dates from the mid 18th century.

([resort to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resort))

> **2** • *formal* go often or in large numbers to: *local authorities have a duty to provide adequate sites for gypsies ‘residing in or resorting to’ their areas*
>    - *These matters are of considerable concern to residents and others resorting to the area.*
>    - *Since the duty relates to the provision of accommodation 'for gipsies residing in or resorting to' the area it is relevant to inquire whether the group visits regularly.*
>    - *In this respect, it is important to consider the manner of trade being proposed; the number and kinds of persons resorting to the area; the expectations of those persons in respect of access to liquor; and the extent to which other premises in the area can meet those expectations.*